Indesign relink cross references from other file to current file
I have used the book tool to create a 1800 page file that has hundreds of crossreferences over multiple documents within the book.
Now I need to make another project that consists of exerpts from the first document in a smaller format in another file.
If I just copy the text and insert it to the other file or if I use the "move page" feature, the links are either lost, or--if the document with the original text anchors is open--refering to the original document.
Is there a way to batch relink the references to the text anchor of the same name in the current file? Could this be solved via a script? Or is there another way?

Interesting challenge. I would like to try, but I can't guarantee success. It depends on the specific layout you have. Can you please share a sample of your work, or something similar that illustrates the problem (e.g., a book with multiple INDD files, cross-references, anchors, etc.)? Also, I am still using InDesign CC 2022. If you have a newer version, that could be a problem (although I might be able to solve it, I can't promise).

Thank you for trying. I use CC24. So I created a book file, as well as a file in which I copy/pasted parts from the book file and downsaved them as idml (I used export and save as, to be save). I'm not sure, if you can open the indb so you probably have to save the idml as indd and create a new indb-file since it doesn't accept the idmls. Man I wish Adobe would make downsaving for recent earlier versions possible. I hope, if you open the files, the crossreferences won't be lost. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qfNpgKFWu5C-H8VMa4N6DgodewGqNLjW?usp=sharing

Ok. I got the files. And it looks I can open the idml files just fine. I see the cross-references. And I see the 'broken' cross-references inside the file 'sample-document_single.idml'. I think they can be fixed with a script. I'll try to figure out the solution.

By the way, you can try to ask this guy directly here: https://creativepro.com/files/kahrel/indesign/text_anchors.html probably it will be faster. I'm not an expert in handling cross-references, I'm afraid it will take a bit time... )

It's totally fine. I'm not expecting anything. I thank you so much for trying anyway. If it works, it would be awesome. If not, well then I have to spent a day or two reassigning crossreferences. And even if you figure it out too late for my project. I believe a script like that will be very appreciated by every ID-User working with crossreferences. I'm afraid Peter Kahrel has retired a year ago. But the skript you linked sounds intresesting. Thank you!

Here https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/merging-multiple-documents-into-one-but-losing-cross-references/m-p/8944765#M46154 is another interesting observation by Kasyan Servetsky on this matter. Perhaps, some manipulations with references should be done to all documents in a book before copying them into a new document.

That's an interesting work around. Sadly, if I understand this right, it renames all destinations to machine-read-only anchors. It shouldn't be a problem if no further referencing is made after pasting the text but otherwise this could be an issue.

I haven't found a proper solution for now. But I managed to get correct cross-references 'manually'. I made a copy of the first file in a book, removed from it all the pages except two empty ones. Then open the indb book (all its files should be opened). Added an empty page at the end of every indd file of the book. And then moved all pages (except the last empty page) each indd file into the end of the empty copy indd file, with the option "Delete Pages After Moving". Here is my result file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lERcGyA87deIiDVh5jwwIl9sCSnugClf?usp=sharing

I'm well aware this is not a proper solution for your case. It's just a way to merge manually the book files into one big indd file. I believe if one will delete the redundant pages/texts from the big indd file (instead of copying texts the book) the cross-references survive.

Moreover, I just tried to move all the pages into the new file without the option 'Delete Pages After Moving' (it's simpler) and I got the correct cross-references in the new indd file. All the links work fine inside the new file, they don't try to open another files of the book.

I Just tried it an it actually works. Thank you! I won't be able to apply this method for my project now, since I'm too close to finish it but it will be a possible workaround for future projects.

I just found out that it also works the other way around. I mean splitting one document in multiple documents for use of the book-tool. But it only works with crossreferences and hyperlinks whose text anchor has already been moved. So if there is a chapter or part that has the majority of crossreferences, this part should be moved last. These will be linked to the anchors in the new files. All the other links will be broken but NOT linked to the previous file. This is really great to know.
